# Setting and Getting Object from Storage in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have this sample login page where I am trying to store the returned object of data (user data) to a storage so I can get it and use it in other pages... since the data is in form of JSON Object (array) ... I'm not sure how this is done, I tried stringify it but something is wrong!

login.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html'
})
export class LoginPage {

  login: {username?: string , password?: string} = {};
  submitted = false;
  loginDetails: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private schoolAppUsers: SchoolAppUsers, public userData: UserData, public storage: Storage, public globalService: GlobalService ) {

    this.globalService=globalService;
    this.schoolAppUsers=schoolAppUsers;
    this.userData=userData;
  } 

  onLogin(form) {

  this.submitted = true;

  if (form.valid) {

    this.schoolAppUsers.login(this.login)
      .then(loginDetails => {

        this.loginDetails = loginDetails;
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(TabsPage);
        // console.log(loginDetails);
      });

    this.userData.login(this.login.username);
    this.userData.loginDetails(this.loginDetails);

  }
}
```

when I console log: `//console.log(loginDetails);` this is the output (object):

> [{"error":"false","UserID":1,"name":"yasir","username":"yasir12","password":"123","role":1}]

So I'm trying to pass it: `this.userData.loginDetails(this.loginDetails);`

userData.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserData {
  constructor(public events: Events, public storage: Storage) {}

  loginDetails(loginDetails) {
    this.setLoginDetails(loginDetails);
  };

  setLoginDetails(loginDetails) {
    this.storage.set('loginDetails', JSON.stringify(loginDetails));
  };

  getLoginDetails() {
    return this.storage.get('loginDetails').then((value) => {
      return value && JSON.parse(value);
    });
  };
```

This is how I am trying to get in other pages, which when I console log it returns `null` or `undefined`

```
 loginDetails: any;

 ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.getUserdetails();
 }

 getUserdetails() {
   this.userData.getLoginDetails().then((loginDetails) => {
     this.loginDetails = loginDetails;
     console.log(this.loginDetails);
   });
}
```

Can someone please help!

Comment: same here also any update for this

Comment: i dont know , im stuck too, even in ionic 2 forum no one replied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (form.valid) {

          this.schoolAppUsers.login(this.login)
         .then(loginDetails => {

          this.loginDetails = loginDetails;
          this.navCtrl.setRoot(TabsPage);
            // console.log(loginDetails);
        });

          this.userData.login(this.login.username);
          this.userData.loginDetails(this.loginDetails);

  }
```

This is the problem .
your promise.then() is asynchronous.
you are trying to save loginDetails in userData even before it is set in this.loginDetails.
you should do:

```
 this.userData.loginDetails(this.loginDetails);
```

inside the then method of login.

UPDATE
change

```
 return value && JSON.parse(value);
```

to

```
 return value || JSON.parse(value);
```

Comment: I still get undefined

Comment: Actually this time i got [object Object] , where are getting close i think

Comment: At getUserdetails() the out put on screen is [object Object]
but under it console.log 
i get undefined

Comment: mr Suraj 
is there a way that i can reserve the type as well , i want the type be Object so i can access its elements... currently whats returned is of type string...i dont know how to properly access it